# How to use 'eww-view-source' in a function?

Tags: org-mode, eww

I need to kill and yank some portion of the source code of multiples websites for a database i'm making of news of certain web. But the problem is, whenever i call `eww-view-source` for viewing the website's source, it gives me an error of "no source".

The function and macro (I made a keyboard macro when the function didn't work) works the first time, but at a second execution it gives me the error.

I'm using an `.org` file with all the links i need to access and copy a portion from their source. This region is determined with two `search-forward` expressions. This is the function i made (ignore the name and description, i'm from Latinoamérica):

```
 (defun aporrea-listar-archivo ()
  "Copia en la entrada el código relativo a las noticias 
de una página del archivo de aporrea."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-open-at-point)
    (set-buffer "*eww*") ;;added this trying to solve
    (eww-view-source)
    (set-buffer "*eww-source*")   ;;added this trying to solve
    (copy-region-as-kill (search-forward "<h1>Noticias</h1>")
             (search-forward "<h1>Artículos de Opinión</h1>"))
    (View-quit)  ;; This exits the view-mode of eww for sources
    (kill-buffer "*eww-source*")
    (kill-buffer "*eww*")))
```

For some reason the `save-excursion` is not working. I'm ok with that...

Answer (score 1):

Try using `eww-after-render-hook`.  e.g.:

```el
(defun aporrea-listar-archivo ()
  "Copia en la entrada el código relativo a las noticias 
de una página del archivo de aporrea."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-open-at-point)
    (set-buffer "*eww*") ;;added this trying to solve
    (add-hook 'eww-after-render-hook
              (lambda ()
                (eww-view-source)
                (set-buffer "*eww-source*")   ;;added this trying to solve
                (copy-region-as-kill (search-forward "<h1>Noticias</h1>")
                                     (search-forward "<h1>Artículos de Opinión</h1>"))
                (View-quit)  ;; This exits the view-mode of eww for sources
                (kill-buffer "*eww-source*")
                (kill-buffer "*eww*"))
              nil :local)))
```

Although, as best I can see you have no interest in the rendered HTML at all, so I can't see a reason to use `eww` for this.  Perhaps something like the following meets your needs?

```el
(url-retrieve
 (url-get-url-at-point)
 (lambda (status)
   (copy-region-as-kill (search-forward "<h1>Noticias</h1>")
                        (search-forward "<h1>Artículos de Opinión</h1>"))
   (kill-buffer)))
```